# WP add to cart and save item meta programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add product along with meta data in cart with programming.
Here is my code. But its not adding any meta data but only adding product in cart.

```
$genre = 10;
$item_id = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, false, false, [ 'genre_id' => $genre, 'genre' => 'Test' ] );
WC()->cart->cart_contents[$item_id]['genre_id'] = $genre;
WC()->cart->cart_contents[$item_id]['genre'] = 'Test';
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
WC()->cart->set_session();
WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();
```

Also added few hooks, that are also not adding meta data.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_item_price', 30, 1 );
function change_cart_item_price( $cart ) {

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        //if( isset($cart_item['genre_id']) ){
            $cart_item['data']->add_meta_data( 'genre_id', $cart_item['genre_id'] );
            $cart_item['data']->add_meta_data( 'genre', 'Test' );
        //}
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', function ( $item_data, $cart_item_data ) {
    //if( isset( $cart_item_data['genre'] ) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key' => 'Genre',
            'value' => 'Test'
        );
    //}
    return $item_data;
}, 10, 2 );


add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', function( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    //if( isset( $values['genre'] ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data(
            'Genre',
            'Test',
            true
        );
    //}
}, 10, 4 );
```

Can you please verify where I'm wrong. I got these code from online search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below action/filter to add additional data to cart item:

```
//Add custom cart item data
function zwtadd_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['what_is_being_promoted'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['zwt_field'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['genre_id'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'zwtadd_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );


//Display custom item data in the cart
function zwt_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item_data ) {
    if( isset( $cart_item_data['zwt_field'] ) ) {
    $item_data[] = array(
        'key' => __( 'Genre id', 'text-domain' ),
        'value' => wc_clean( $cart_item_data['zwt_field'] )
    );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'zwt_get_item_data', 10, 2 );

//Add custom meta to order
function zwt_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset( $values['zwt_field'] ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data(__( 'Genre id', 'text-domain' ), $values['zwt_field'], true);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'zwt_checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4 );
```

Above code will add data to cart item, display data to cart and same will display in the order.